# Ubuntu Software shows up as mounted disk?

Tags: mount, software-center, snap, autostart

Just recently, a new 53 MB volume showed up in Nautilus with the path `media/qwr/disk`.

[image]

I looked in the autostart directory and it had two files.

setup-autostart:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -r $GS_SELF_TEST_OS_RELEASE_FILENAME ];
then
  if [[ "$(grep "^NAME" $GS_SELF_TEST_OS_RELEASE_FILENAME | awk -F '"' '{print $2}')" == "Ubuntu" ]];
  then
    # Delete autostart and recreate to handle migration to ubuntu-software snap
    # FIXME: Remove the following line after revision > 214 and < 352 is the majority
    rm -rf $SNAP_USER_DATA/.config/autostart
    if [[ ! -d "$SNAP_USER_DATA/.config/autostart" ]];
    then
      mkdir -p $SNAP_USER_DATA/.config/autostart
      ln -sfnt $SNAP_USER_DATA/.config/autostart/ ${SNAP/`basename $SNAP`/current}/autostart/ubuntu-software-service.desktop
    fi
  fi
fi

exec "$@"
```

and `ubuntu-software-service.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ubuntu Software
Exec=snap-store.ubuntu-software --gapplication-service %U
X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
NoDisplay=true
```

Why did Ubuntu Software show up as a mounted disk? How can I prevent this from occurring?

Comment: you do not need to prevent it as Ubuntu software is a snap and snaps are mounted

Comment: not sure why it appeared in Nautilus though